Symmetric coupling energy calculation using DFT
I was reading a paper where they wrote down the formula for coupling energy for A-A bond on top of a catalyst.
Assuming there is a catalyst where A-A bonding assisted by the substrate catalyst. Here A atom comes from two different precursor molecules. So the coupling energy was written by:
$$E_{clpg}=[E_{total(product)}+E_{substrate}]-[E_{total(precursor 1)}+E_{total(precursor 2)}]$$
This was substituted eventually by:
$$E_{clpg}=E_{ad(product)}-E_{ad(precursor 1)}-E_{ad(precursor 2)}$$
where,
$$E_{ad}=E_{total}-E_{substrate}-E_{species}$$
I understand the last equation is just adsorption energy of any gas species. Could someone please explain the coupling energy equation?
Edit: Coupling energy $E_{clpg}$ is defined as the difference between total energy following coupling and the total energy of the two precursors before coupling.
Edit: The reference of the same equation can be found in equation 2 and 3 of this paper.




It would probably be helpful to provide the reference/link for the paper in question for more context.

I added the link to the paper @Anyon
